# Passport validity for H1B visa stamping

Tags: usa, h1-visa, passport

I got my H1b approved. I need to go for visa stamping and my passport is about to expire in next 10 months. Is it OK to go with current passport or do I need to renew it before going to visa stamping?

Comment: Could we have an update on that? Did you actually renewed your passport?

Comment: Yes, I renewed my passport.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Department of State](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/employment/temporary.html) one of the required documents listed is passport with validity 6 months beyond your period of stay in the United States:

> **Passport valid for travel to the United States** - Your passport must be valid for at least six months beyond your period of stay in the United States (unless exempt by country-specific agreements). If more than one person is included in your passport, each person who needs a visa must submit a separate application.

Depending on which country you're from your passport may [still be valid 6 past expiration](http://www.state.gov/documents/organization/104770.pdf).

The thing is that your possible period of stay for [H1B is 3 years](http://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/temporary-workers/h-1b-specialty-occupations-dod-cooperative-research-and-development-project-workers-and-fashion-models):

> As an H-1B nonimmigrant, you may be admitted for a period of up to three years. Your time period may be extended, but generally cannot go beyond a total of six years, though some exceptions do apply under sections 104(c) and 106(a) of the American Competitiveness in the Twenty-First Century Act (AC21).

Given that you should renew your passport.

Comment: The link for the list of countries whose passport is valid for an additional six months has been updated, and is now at https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/documents/Six%20Month%20Club%20Update_0.pdf